# How do I input and output various file types in c++

Tags: c++, io, file-type

I've seen a lot of examples of i/o with text files I'm just wondering if you can do the same with other file types like mp3's, jpg's, zip files, etc..?

Will iostream and fstream work for all of these or do I need another library?  Do I need a new sdk?

It's all binary data so I'd think it would be that simple.  But I've been unpleasently surprised before.

Could I convert all files to text or binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work on binary streams by opening them with openmode [binary](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/openmode/) :

```
ifstream ifs("mydata.mp3", ios_base::binary);
```

Then you read and write any binary content. However, if you need to generate or modify such content, play a video or display a piture, the you you need to know the inner details of the format you are using.  This can be exremely complex, so a library would be recomended.  And even with a library, advanced programming skills are required.

Examples of open source libraries:  [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) for usual audio/video format, [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) for audio, [CImg](http://cimg.eu/) for image processing (in C++),  [libpng](http://www.libpng.org) for png graphic format, [lipjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) for jpeg.  Note that most libraries offer a C api.

Some OS also supports some native file types (example, [windows bitmaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Very useful command.  Thank you for that.  Now if I have to download all these libraries will it be easy to get them into Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Only download what you need to use for your specific program, if you are not going to use audio, why import to VS `portaudio`? About your second inquire, if you follow the installation documentation on each project you should be using them in no time with VS... Keep in mind you also need to learn how to use them

Comment: These are all cross-platform libraries, provided in source format. Some of them have instructions how to build them with VS 2010. Some of them a build script using NMAKE (but assuming NMAKE is in the path file and environment variables are set correctly).  It's not always a peice of cake ;-)

Comment: I confirm:  choos either ffmpeg or portaudio.  Browse through the dos to see which seems to you the most easy to use.  For CImg,  it's a kind of front-end to several other libraries, so you might need all ot them.

Answer (score 2):

It depend on what you mean by *"work"*

You can think of those files as *a book written in Greek*.

If you want to just mess with binary representation (*display text in Greek on screen*) then yes, you can do that.

If you want to actually extract some info: edit video stream, remove voice from audio (*actually understand what is written*), then you would need to either parse file format yourself (*learn Greek*) or use some specialized library (*hire a translator*).

Either way, filestreams are suited to actually access those files data (and many libraries do use them under the hood)

Comment: Are these specialized libraries a part of the standard c library?  Are they included in visual studio 2010.

Comment: @Mindril , no, they are not. You need to download them and set up for file types you want. There are propositions to add libraries for working with certain file types in C++ standard, but I doubt any of them would find their way in Standard before 2020

Answer (score 0):

You can open these files using fstream, but the important thing to note is you must be intricately aware of what is contained within the file in order to process it.

If you just want to open it and spit out junk, then you can definitely just start at the first line of the file and exhaustively push all data into your console.

If you know what the file looks like on the inside, then you can process it just as you would any other file.

There may be specific libraries for processing specific files, but the `fstream` library will allow you to access any file you'd like.

Comment: So basically I can access all the bits but I have to know what bits do what.

Answer (score 0):

All files are just bytes.  There's nothing stopping you from reading/writing those bytes however you see fit.

The trick is doing something *useful* with those bytes.  You could read the bytes from a .jpg file, for example, but you have to know what those bytes mean, and that's [complicated](http://www.fileformat.info/format/jpeg/egff.htm).  Usually it's best to use libraries written by people who know about the format in question, and let them deal with that complexity.

Comment: Looks like you guys are all on the same page.  I need to read a bit further.  Since I've asked all the good questions I can think of atm, I'll ask a stupid one :P (maybe)  If I feed a file into my compiler and scramble it a dozen ways, then change it back or do nothing to it and spit it back out, will that file be the same, with the same behavior or does feeding it automatically change it in some way.  I'm guessing no but it doesn't hurt to be sure.

Comment: Bytes are bytes.  Scrambling and unscrambling them doesn't change them.  That's exactly what things like compression and encryption do.